# sed/awk/grep parse email on filtered txt files

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have several txt files and would like to extract email from that file if file contains text "Provider" inside. Text files are not equally formatted. "provider" could be anywhere in text.

Here is some short sample : 
**file 1.txt**

Name: Joe1
Provider
...
Email joe1@joe1.com

**file 2.txt**

Name: Joe2
...
Client
...
Email joe2@joe2.com

**file 3.txt**

Name: Joe3
...
Provider
Email joe3@joe3.com

I am using this short code but it returns all emails

```
$ awk -F, '{
  for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
    if ($i ~ /@/)
       print $i
}' *
```

Can you help me out?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'FNR==1 { provider = False } 
       $0 ~ /Provider/ { provider = True} 
       $0 ~ /@/ && provider == True {
         for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
           if ($i ~ /@/) print $i;
         }
       }' *
```

- For each file set `provider` to `False` in the first line
- If a line contains `Provider` set provider to `True`
- If a line contains an `@` and the word `Provider` was seen before, iterate over the fields and print those which contain the `@`

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
for fname in file*.txt
do
    if grep 'Provider' ${fname} &> /dev/null ; then
       grep -oP 'Email[[:space:]]*\K(.*@.*)' ${fname}
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -l Provider file*.txt | xargs grep -o '[^@[:space:]]+@[^@[:space:]]+'
```

There are more accurate regexps for email addresses out there, e.g. `[0-9a-zA-Z._%+-]+@[0-9a-zA-Z.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}`, if you need to get more precise.